# How to add new dictionaries to an existing Key in a dictionary python

Tags: python

I have this predefined dicitonary :

```
customMappingDict = {'Validated' : '',
                 'notValidated' : ''}
```

I want to add new dictionaries(!?) if possible to the existing key as its value, as in :

```
customMappingDict = {'Validated' : 'Key: 'Value', Key1: 'Value'',
                 'notValidated' : 'Key: 'Value', Key1: 'Value''}
```

For the resulting dictionary I would like to call upon the two preexisting keys(Validated and notValidated) and cycle the keys from its value(!?) as so :

```
for key in customMappingDict['Validated'].keys():
    pass

...
```

Output should be :

```
key, key1
```

What I've tried :

```
if condition:
    str1 = '{}'.format(provLst[0])
    customMappingDict['Validated']: dict[str1]= '{}'.format(provLst[1])
else:
    str2 = '{}'.format(provLst[0])
    customMappingDict['notValidated']: dict[str2] = '{}'.format(provLst[1])
```

The worning that i'm getting in PyCharm :

```
Class 'type' does not define '__getitem__', so the '[]' operator cannot be used on its instances
```

Comment: You should fix your quotation marks.

Comment: Side note: *"Before you downvote me [...]"*. Downvotes are not to you, the user. They're just a measure of the quality and relevance of the question, in order to promote good quality and filter out bad ones. Don't take it as a personal offence if someone downvotes your question, but rather ask what's the reason and try to improve the quality ;)

Comment: did not get what you are trying to do here - customMappingDict['Validated']: dict[str1]= '{}'.format(provLst[1])

Comment: @Nitheesh As described above, i want to add a new dictionary for an existing key in the current dictionary, if this is a valid scenario.

Comment: So you want to add a new dict as a value to an existing dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `collections.defaultdict` will save you a lot of the headache. The idea of `defaultdict` is to create a dictionary that has a default value. In this case, the default value will be a dictionary as well.

You can do that simply like so:

```
from collections import defaultdict


customMappingDict = defaultdict(dict)
if condition:
    str1 = '{}'.format(provLst[0])
    customMappingDict['Validated'][str1] = f'{provLst[1]}'
else:
    str2 = '{}'.format(provLst[0])
    customMappingDict['notValidated'][str2] = f'{provLst[1]}'
```

SideNote: `f{provLst[0]}` is the same as `'{}'.format(provLst[0])` just cleaner !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Suppose i have a dict

```
d = {'red': 100, 'green': 1000}
```

Now I want to change the value of 'red' to a dict

```
d['red'] = dict()
d['red']['light_red'] = 100.10
d['red']['dark_red'] = 100.20
```

Now will be

```
{'red': {'light_red': 100.10, 'dark_red': 100.20}, 'green': 1000}
```